# Fill inputs with Data

Tags: html, angularjs

I am trying to get Data from DB for an Edit form with this an edit button :

```
<button ui-sref="dashboard.modifierCand" type="button" class="btn btn-outline btn-info" ng-click="update(item._id)">Editer</button>
```

this button will show me a new form for editing :

HTML :

```
<input type="text" class="form-control"  ng-model="newlogin">
```

AngularJS :

```
   $scope.update = function (id) { 
        console.log("this is the id " + id)
        $http ({
            header: 'content-type:application/json',
            url: '/ReadCandById/' + id,
            method: 'GET', 
        }).success(function (user) { 
            $scope.user = user[0];
           $scope.newlogin = user[0].Login;
           console.log($scope.newlogin) 
        })
    }
```

in the console i can see the id and the login but it can't be in the input

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using JQuery to change the value of the input field?

Comment: Where are you callin the `update` function?

Comment: I have the table of all users and i have a button of edit <button ui-sref="dashboard.modifierCand" type="button" class="btn btn-outline btn-info" ng-click="update(item._id)">Editer</button>

Comment: @MarouenAyadi Can you please update your question with this code it will be more helpful? :)

Comment: you dont need jquery for this!!! just assign the value to the ng-model.

Comment: Also jquery is not a solution

Comment: You said *in the console i can see the id and the login but it can't be in the input*, does the `user.Login`hold both the `id` and the `Login`??

Comment: It hold all data

Comment: What is your Angular version?

Comment: What is the value of `$scope.newLogin` if you log it to cconsole?

Comment: AngularJS v1.2.16

Comment: @chsdk Bonbr (the login)

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBJB2.png

Comment: @MarouenAyadi can you please share your `dashboard.modifierCand` state configuration? odes it use the same controller ?

Comment: I use the same controller

Comment: @MarouenAyadi:  check if  `$scope.newlogin` not overridden after your load, ?